# Preposition for phone number to say "you called me at X"

Tags: preposition, grammaticality

Someone called me about requiring to do some maintenance work in my apartment. Instead of calling back I'll respond by email.

In the email, I'd like to give some context about me: my name, where I live and the phone number they called.

Is *unter* the correct preposition to use when I want to say *you called me this morning at 123456*?

My email will start with:

> Mein Name is Peter, ich wohne in der Hauptstrasse 123.
> Sie haben mich heute Morgen **unter** 1234567 angerufen über meine Balkontür zu messen. […]

Comment: Welcome! I took the liberty to remove the rest of the text - this community is a bit sensitive when it comes to bulk translation or proofreading requests.

Comment: Some remarks: *About measuring* cannot be translated as *über zu messen*, it would be something like *wegen der Ausmessung meiner Balkontür*. Outside of Switzerland and Liechtenstein, *Straße* is written with an *ß*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "unter 32168" oder "unter der Nummer 32168" are fine here. "Unter der 32168" is also quite common colloquially. Some people also use "auf der Nummer 32168" or "auf der 32168".

> Mein Name is Peter, ich wohne in der Hauptstraße 123. Sie haben mich heute Morgen unter [der Nummer] 1234567 angerufen, weil Sie meine Balkontür ausmessen wollen. […]

BTW, "anrufen über [ein Thema]" isn't used in German. It's mostly "anrufen wegen" or "anrufen zum Thema", and there is no way to say this as shortly and simply as "you called me about measuring my balcony door".

Some ways to say this:

> Sie haben mich [...] angerufen wegen des Ausmessens meiner Balkontür.
> Sie haben mich [...] angerufen, um über das Ausmessen meiner Balkontür zu sprechen.
> Sie haben mich [...] angerufen, weil Sie meine Balkontür ausmessen wollen/sollen/müssen.

Reference: this 1980s "Neue Deutsche Welle" song: https://youtu.be/qaONT_O0gjI?t=89 The band paid for a Munich retirement home to get a new number.

Comment: An even shorter version would be "Sie haben mich wegen meiner Balkontür angerufen. Of course this omits the information about measuring, but this might be clear to the concerned person. (There is different hearsay about the phone number mentionend in the song, see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skandal_im_Sperrbezirk#Telefonnummer_32168)